# how to get variable starting with double-underscore displayed in eclipse/pydev debug view

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev

In the eclipse/pydev debug view, if a dict object has a key starting with double-underscore, like { "__my_key": , ...}, that key won't show up in the variables view in debug mode; the other keys all show up as expected.
Is there a setting to change to get the double-underscore key displayed in debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

Double-underscore keys are considered private in Python therefore you are not able to see them outside the class. You can use "watch" while debugging or print out to the console the data that you need though.